# C language: float % float why expression must have integral type

Tags: c

I try to do this operation so see if this operation will take only the complete part `(20%4)` or all `(20.4%4.4)`

```
float x = 20.4;
float y = 4.0;
float z;
z = x%y;
```

And got this compiler `error`:

> expression must have integral type

Comment: Look up how to use fmod.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `%` for getting the remainder of integer divisions.

To get the remainder of a floating-point division, use the [`fmod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html) function instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `modff` to get the issue resolved.

```
float res = modff(x,&y)
```

The integral part is stored in `y` and the fractional part is returned. `%` can't be used with non-integral types.

Answer (score 0):

cannot modulo floats. a way around this.

```
float x = 20.4
int xint = (int)(x);
int y = 4;
float z = x % y + (x-xint)
```